# Can $e^{a|x|^b}$ be written in terms of an integral?

Tags: integration, exponential-function

I know that $e^{a|x|}$ can be written as

$$
e^{-a|x|}=\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{a}{\sqrt{2\pi y}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2y}}e^{-\frac{a^2y}{2}}dy
$$

but can $e^{a|x|^b}$ be written in terms of an integral?

Comment: The more interesting question is actually how this integral is derived. Can you provide either a proof or a reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One may just put $|x|:=|x|^b$ into the *given integral* to obtain
$$
e^{-a|x|^b}=\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{a}{\sqrt{2\pi y}}e^{-\large\frac{x^{2b}}{2y}}e^{-\large\frac{a^2y}{2}}dy.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your equation is true, you can simply substitute $x^b$ for $x$ to obtain
$$e^{-a|x|^b}=\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{a}{\sqrt{2\pi y}}e^{-\frac{x^{2b}}{2y}}e^{-\frac{a^2y}{2}}dy$$
The reason this is possible is that the integral is with respect to $y$, treating $x$ constant, and $|x^b|=|x|^b$.